# Cannot detect client mac address using Javascript ActiveXObject On Windows 8

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to get client mac address using JavaScript ActiveXObject On Windows 8 but it didn't work.

actually it works fine on windows 7.

Here is My Code:

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
var s = obj.ConnectServer(".");
var properties = s.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
var e = new Enumerator(properties);
var output;
var outputTemp = "";
var Number6MacAddress = "";
var ReturnedMACAddresesses = "";
output = '<table border="0" cellPadding="5px" cellSpacing="1px" bgColor="#CCCCCC">';
outputTemp = '';
output = output + '<tr bgColor="#EAEAEA"><td>Caption</td><td>MACAddress</td></tr>';
var Counter = 0;
while (!e.atEnd()) {
  e.moveNext();
  var p = e.item();
  if (!p) continue;
  output = output + '<tr bgColor="#FFFFFF">';
  output = output + '<td>' + p.Caption; +'</td>';
  output = output + '<td>' + p.MACAddress + '</td>';
  //output = output + '<td>' + p.Properties_[43].Value + '</td>';
  output = output + '</tr>';
}
```

**In Windows 7 it gives the following result:**

**Notice That ID [00000007] detected Network card MACAddress Successfully and this what i am using.**

```html
Caption MACAddress 
[00000001] WAN Miniport (IKEv2) null 
[00000002] WAN Miniport (L2TP) null 
[00000003] WAN Miniport (PPTP) null 
[00000004] WAN Miniport (PPPOE) null 
[00000005] WAN Miniport (IPv6) null 
[00000006] WAN Miniport (Network Monitor) null 
[00000007] Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20) 50:E5:49:FC:4D:3F 
[00000008] WAN Miniport (IP) null 
[00000009] Microsoft ISATAP Adapter null 
[00000010] RAS Async Adapter null 
[00000011] Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter null 
[00000012] Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device null 
[00000013] Microsoft ISATAP Adapter null
```

**But on Windows 8 it gives me the following result**

**NOTICE: My Network Card is not on the list?
I don't know why?**

```html
Caption  -  MACAddress 

[00000001] - Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter null 

[00000002] - Microsoft ISATAP Adapter null 

[00000003] - Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter null
```

any ideas?

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a valid error at all. What's the error? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: What error do you get? What are you running this in?

Comment: i tried debugging and on win 8 'p.MACAddress' property is always null

Comment: What properties does it have? What adapter is it?

Comment: I've added results on both windows 7 and windows 8 for the same machine

Comment: Your code works for me on Win 8.1. The problem is that it's not finding any network adapter with a MAC address on it. Do you actually have a configured network card on the Win 8 box running the code?

Comment: it works on win 8? and returned a MACAddress?

Comment: My network card is configured and i can access internet successfully

Comment: Yes... here's the result (pixelated the MAC Addresses): http://i61.tinypic.com/2rogidw.png

Comment: No errors on the Javascript console either

Comment: So why does it return null for me?

Comment: It's returning null on 3 adapters that don't have a mac address. Your question should be: "why is not listing my actual network card"? And for that, I don't have an answer

Comment: i will update the question to be as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is skipping the first result of the query (that is, the first network interface, with ID 00000000 normally) which might happen to be the only one with a MAC address on your Windows 8 box.

Move the `e.moveNext()` to the end of the loop and see if it shows now:

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
var s = obj.ConnectServer(".");
var properties = s.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
var e = new Enumerator(properties);
var output = '<table border="0" cellPadding="5px" cellSpacing="1px" bgColor="#CCCCCC">';
output = output + '<tr bgColor="#EAEAEA"><td>Caption</td><td>MACAddress</td></tr>';
while (!e.atEnd()) {
  var p = e.item();
  if (!p) continue;
  output = output + '<tr bgColor="#FFFFFF">';
  output = output + '<td>' + p.Caption; +'</td>';
  output = output + '<td>' + p.MACAddress + '</td>';
  output = output + '</tr>';
  e.moveNext();
}
output = output + '</table>';
```